# Mocha: run tests in parallel and serial mode

Tags: mocha.js, teamcity

I use mocha for running tests and mocha-teamcity-reporter as a reporter for teamcity.
I have test files that can be run in parallel. And also I have some test files that should be run one by one - in serial mode.
As I understood mocha documentation, mocha can run test files only in parallel or in serial mode. So I tried to do the following: run two mocha runs with & command in one yarn script, like this:

```
mocha --reporter mocha-teamcity-reporter --timeout 90000 -r ts-node/register/transpile-only src/Tests/.ts --parallel --jobs 4 & mocha --reporter mocha-teamcity-reporter --timeout 90000 -r ts-node/register/transpile-only src/Tests/seq.ts
```

But using this approach for some reason reporter does not work properly and TeamCity does not detect all tests that were run. Is there any way to run tests like I want with mocha and mocha-teamcity-reporter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems that this is the only way to do it. Mentioned issue with tests detecting was resolved in one of the recent mocha updates.